# “User request limit reached” Issue in Facebook Ads api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using [this example code on Github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/blob/master/examples/adgroup_creation.php) to create a Facebook Ad I'm running into the following error, after running this code just twice:

`User request limit reached`

How is it possible I'm reaching this limit after 2x8 API calls?

Below the CurlLogger() output (note that I obfuscated `access_token`, `appsecret_proof` and `account id` for security reasons):

```
curl -G \
  -d 'fields=id,name,account_status' \
  -d 'access_token=XXXXXXXX' \
  -d 'appsecret_proof=YYYYYYYY' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_XYZ

curl \
  -F 'name=My campaign title' \
  -F 'objective=LINK_CLICKS' \
  -F 'execution_options=["validate_only"]' \
  -F 'access_token=XXXXXXXX' \
  -F 'appsecret_proof=YYYYYYYY' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_XYZ/campaigns

curl \
  -F 'name=My campaign title' \
  -F 'objective=LINK_CLICKS' \
  -F 'status=PAUSED' \
  -F 'access_token=XXXXXXXX' \
  -F 'appsecret_proof=YYYYYYYY' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_XYZ/campaigns

curl \
  -F 'name=My first adset' \
  -F 'campaign_id=6075675640104' \
  -F 'daily_budget=100' \
  -F 'targeting={"geo_locations":{"cities":[{"key":172964,"radius":10,"distance_unit":"mile"}]}}' \
  -F 'optimization_goal=REACH' \
  -F 'billing_event=IMPRESSIONS' \
  -F 'bid_amount=10' \
  -F 'start_time=2017-06-14T21:41:11-0700' \
  -F 'end_time=2017-06-21T21:41:11-0700' \
  -F 'execution_options=["validate_only"]' \
  -F 'access_token=XXXXXXXX' \
  -F 'appsecret_proof=YYYYYYYY' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_XYZ/adsets

curl \
  -F 'name=My first adset' \
  -F 'campaign_id=6075675640104' \
  -F 'daily_budget=100' \
  -F 'targeting={"geo_locations":{"cities":[{"key":172964,"radius":10,"distance_unit":"mile"}]}}' \
  -F 'optimization_goal=REACH' \
  -F 'billing_event=IMPRESSIONS' \
  -F 'bid_amount=10' \
  -F 'start_time=2017-06-14T21:41:11-0700' \
  -F 'end_time=2017-06-21T21:41:11-0700' \
  -F 'status=ACTIVE' \
  -F 'access_token=XXXXXXXX' \
  -F 'appsecret_proof=YYYYYYYY' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_XYZ/adsets

curl \
  -F 'filename=@/Localhost/www_example_com/images/test.png' \
  -F 'access_token=XXXXXXXX' \
  -F 'appsecret_proof=YYYYYYYY' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_XYZ/adimages

curl \
  -F 'name=Sample Creative' \
  -F 'title=Welcome to the Jungle' \
  -F 'body=We\'ve got fun \'n\' games' \
  -F 'image_hash=72b3cf2aab4b0846321347ac4019cc52' \
  -F 'object_url=https://www.example.com/test.html' \
  -F 'access_token=XXXXXXXX' \
  -F 'appsecret_proof=YYYYYYYY' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_XYZ/adcreatives

curl \
  -F 'creative={"creative_id":"6075663629104"}' \
  -F 'name=My First Ad' \
  -F 'adset_id=6075675640904' \
  -F 'access_token=XXXXXXXX' \
  -F 'appsecret_proof=YYYYYYYY' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_XYZ/ads
```

Comment: It is doing 5 calls

Comment: @WizKid Fair enough, but why do I get rate limited after 2 x 5 calls?